# Make all cookies secure in a JSF Application

Tags: jsf, web.xml

How can I make all cookies secure in a Java Web / JSF Application?

I added the following lines to web.xml to make JSESSIONID secure and httpOnly. Yet, the other cookies are not secure.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        15
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
        <max-age>6000</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

If that can be achieved by changing the web.xml file, that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie can be arbitrarily created and attached to the response by your code or by the code of the frameworks that you use. The default value of the `secure` flag is `false`, according to the [servlet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setSecure-boolean-). You can use `Cookie.setSecure()` method to set this flag to `true` for any particular cookie, but there's no way to enforce this flag to always be true. You'd have to solve this issue for every particular case.

Comment: I am not explicitly creating cookies, they are JSF-generated cookies. Ex. cookiesession1. How can I control them?

Comment: Maybe PrimeFaces generated cookies

Comment: I don't have such cookies in my JSF/PrimeFaces application. This might be something not related to your application at all. This sounds like something that might have been injected by FortiWeb or some other firewall, see e.g. https://help.fortinet.com/fweb/582/Content/FortiWeb/fortiweb-admin/http_sessions_security.htm

Comment: The cookie was injected by the WAF.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this selected answer above is correct for what you're asking. It's true that you can create a secure cookie using that method, but you're asking about the session cookie, which is not created using the method he describes.

The configuration you have is correct though, but only works if your container supports it.

- You must be on a recent lineage of tomcat (7.x, 8.x, 9.x, etc)
- You must use the latest version in the lineage (9.0.64 at the time of this writing)
- Your web.xml must declare/use a supported schema. You only posted a snippet of your web.xml. I checked the web-common_3_0.xsd and it has the http-only and secure elements in it. As such, you must use web.xml schema of 3.0 or greater:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0">
```

I tested this locally on the most recent version of Tomcat 9 and the cookie was produced correctly.

Comment: The gist of the question was, how to make ALL cookies in the application secure, not just the Tomcat session cookies (this one the OP has already figured out). To that end I believe my answer is correct.